# Regex syntax issues objective-c

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsrange

```
NSString *inputStr=@"AA.BB Hello \nCC.JJ Say \nBB.CC Bye \nZZ.AA To";
NSRange r;
while ((r=[inputStr rangeOfString:@"(^[A-L].*)" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location!=NSNotFound)  {
    NSString *newStr=[inputStr substringWithRange:r];
    inputStr=[inputStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"NEW str= %@",newStr);
}
```

It gives: AA.BB Hello.

But, I am looking for suffix which are in the range A-L, as below

AA.BB

CC.JJ

BB.CC

Then I replaced `(^[A-L].\*)` by `(^[A-L]*$[\\s])` . So it must start from A-L and end when it finds space. But this outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Try `([A-L]+\\.[^\\s]*)`.

`[^\\s]*` will match everything that is not a space.

This gives me:

```
NEW str= AA.BB
NEW str= CC.JJ
NEW str= BB.CC
```